# Prestashop shipping cost modification

Tags: php, prestashop, cart

I need Prestashop to calculate shipping price depend on items quantity in cart.
If there is more than one item in cart, i want the shipping price to be 50% of sum of all shipping costs.

I modyfied the cart module, but when i proceed to order page, the shipping cost is still full amount.

My code in blockcart:

```
if($nbTotalProducts>1) {
    $shipping_cost_float = $shipping_cost_float/2;
    $shipping_cost = $shipping_cost/2;
}
```

How can i store new shipping cost for all modules/controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, i found the solution.

I have modified the cart class (classes/cart.php) - getPackageShippingCost function.

I add this code before the shipping cost is converting to float:

```
$product_array = $this->getProducts();
$pcount = 0; //quantity of products in cart
$moreThanOneQuantity = FALSE;
  foreach($product_array as $product_item) {
    $pcount++;
    if($product_item['quantity']>1) $moreThanOneQuantity = TRUE;
  }
if($shipping_cost>0 && ($pcount>1 || $moreThanOneQuantity )) $shipping_cost=$shipping_cost/2;
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is not that simple to manipulate shipping cost. They depends on the carrier used for the cart. I think you should try to set fixed value in the carrier option, and define many price range.

If it's not enough, the best solution for me is to use a new cartrule. Create one that give free shipping, and override CartRule class. In the method getContextualValue, the shipping cost is setted to 0 here. i think you may change it to remove 50% instead. You may have to change some template rendering too (your cart will display a free shipping).

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to code here. You can try to play with the weights of the productos.

For example, you put all your items with weight 1 and you configure your shipping cost to be 50% more if the weight is up to 1. This way you will have what you want if I understood correctly

Comment: Thank You for Your comment, but the problem is, that the shipping price is depend on product, not the carrier (my client is an unconventional...). So i can't add ranges and assign them amounts, because these amounts are variable and depend on sum of shipping costs of currently selected products.